# Copied empty folder on top of C:\ using xcopy - what happened?

Tags: windows-10, filesystem-corruption, xcopy

I was testing `xcopy` on Windows 10 for use in scripts and, in haste, I run:

`xcopy /s /e /y /x "%~dp0/aaaaaaaaaa" "C:/"`

where `aaaaaaaaaa` is an empty folder. 
`/s /e /y /x` does the copy recursively, including empty folders, not prompting before overwriting and preserving permissions.

I suppose that this command, if successful, will overwrite `C:\` with `aaaaaaaaaa`.

I did not record the output of the command but it did manage to have the following effects:

- Windows shut down and boot normally.
- On `My Computer` the C: drive does not report its size and cannot be opened: [image: C DRIVE] [image: access denied]
- I cannot run most `exe` files neither by browsing to them via `explorer` nor via running `cmd` using the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut (trying to run `cmd` by browsing to `system32` fails)

[image]
[image]

- I can browse to all `C:\` directories normally, via `explorer`, **except** the root of `C:\`.
- Running some programs is allowed via <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (like `explorer` and `cmd` but not `devmgmt.msc`)
- I cannot start System restore neither from Windows nor from the Windows DVD:
  [image]
- `chkdsk` does not find anything out of the ordinary.

So, mainly, my question is:

What did that command do, exactly? I suppose it did not overwrite over the partition table or else I would not be able to boot, correct? 
Once I understand that, I should be able to find the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /x switch copies file ownership and ACLs. My suspicion is that the permissions on the drive root may have changed. Check them against a known good computer with the same OS. If they are altered, you'll have to try to restore them.

Comment: It was indeed a permissions issue. Thank you so much!